# Using XamlReader to parse Silverlight based XAML files

Tags: .net, wpf, parsing, xaml

Wrote a simple WPF application in order to parse Silverlight based xaml files:

```
System.Windows.Controls.UserControl uc = (System.Windows.Controls.UserControl)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
```

but when I run it I get: `'Missing key value on 'Storyboard' object.' Line number '1' and line position '467'.`

and also gives an error for `TargetProperty`'s: `Failed to create a 'TargetProperty' from the text '(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)'.' Line number '1' and line position '603`

I think it is using WPF schema, so how can I fix it to work with silverlight schema?